# Initializing default values of a React hook form using Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, redux-toolkit

I am having a hard time assigning a default value to a React hook form using a React Redux object.

I am using react-hook-form, Redux toolkit, and materiauli. It appears that the problem is with the TextField of materialui, but I can't still solve it.

**Initialization**

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const category = useSelector(state => state.inventory.categories.category)

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getCategoryData(id))
}, [])
```

**Initialization of React Hook Form**

```js
const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    name: category.name
  }
})
```

**JSX is not working**

```
< TextField
  name='name'
  id='name'
  label='name'
  variant='outlined'
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
  }}
  className={classes.form__item}
  inputRef={register}
/>
```

Comment: Are you using this library https://react-hook-form.com/? Please mention it in your question. Also, please mention which UI framework you are using.

Comment: Have you tried passing default value directly to the text field? `<TextField defaultValue={category.name} /*... */ />`.

Comment: yes. i did it like this  defaultValue={category.name}

Comment: but its not working.. its working for plain text, but when I did this -   value={category.name} it  is working..also this is working -<input defaultValue={category.name}/>

Answer (score 4):

this is likely a rendering issue, where the form hook establishes the default values before redux completes its data fetching. for example, if you added an additional `useEffect` clause using `reset` from `useForm`, i suspect the form would populate with default values.

```
const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    name: category.name
  }
})

useEffect(() => {
  reset({ name: category.name })
},[category])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use watch and useEffect to updated your default values after dispatch.

```js
const form = useSelector("your reducer");

const { register, handleSubmit, reset, watch } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    name: form?.name ?? ''
  }
})

useEffect(() => {
    reset({name: form?.name})
}, [form, watch])
```